# Insert Rails Migration Between Two Existing Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite, migration

I created the following migration:

```rb
class FixVoteColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        rename_column :votes, :post_id, :votable_id
        add_column :votes, :votable_type, :string
      end
    end
```

And then mistakenly created this migration, renaming the column again:

```
class ChangeVoteTableColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :votes, :post_id, :votable_id
  end
end
```

This obviously raises an error upon running rake db:migrate:

```
==  FixVoteColumnName: migrating ==============================================
-- rename_column(:votes, :post_id, :votable_id)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Missing column votes.post_id
```

When I first saw this error, I simply deleted the second migration (as in, moved it to my Trash folder), ran rake db:migrate again, and moved on. After that point, I created 3 migrations and ran them successfully.

When I pushed to Heroku, this proved problematic. Somehow, Heroku was still processing the deleted migration. I got it working by running heroku run rake db:schema:reload but I know that isn't a long-term solution.

I think what I need to do is move the second migration back into my db/migrate directory and inserting a migration between the two that renames :votable_id back to :post_id so that the second migration can run properly. I've could also run rake db:rollback, but since there have been a few migrations since the problematic migration, that might get messy.

Any ideas on how I can solve this responsibly? This is just a fun project so dropping the database isn't the end of the world, but I would like to learn how to do it the *right* way, if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrations are fantastic in so many ways, but once you muddle with prior migrations with subsequent migrations having been run, then their beauty crumbles and it can be a real headache to fix.

If this is just for fun, I'd just fix your migrations so that all migrations are accurate and build on prior migrations. Don't leave out any steps. Then revert to the very beginning of your migrations, followed by a remigration..

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
rake db:migrate
```

If I am rapidly building an app that is not live, I'll often migrate back to VERSION 0, then consolidate my migrations, so that I have one migration that builds a resource, and I find it just looks more organized, but its hardly necessary.

As a rule, I'd suggest **never deleting/modifying migrations that are behind the current migration**. In development this can create a hassle, as you found, and when you are live, this can be agonizing (and risky) to fix.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a the deleted migration file in your github repository.

Make sure you have committed the deletion of this file.

`git status` will let you know if there is any difference...

to commit the deleted file:

```
git add -u 
git commit -m "file deleted"
```

Now you can push to your github and heroku

```
git push
git push heroku
```

Heroku should not see the old migration anymore...